# Why is my soy milk frozen?

Tags: storage-method, freezing, soymilk

I bought a quart of soy milk for the first time ever last week. It has been sitting unopened in the door of my refrigerator since. I pulled it out today to use it in a bowl of cereal and it was frozen *solid*.

My refrigerator is not particularly frigid; regular milk and juice products stored in the back do not freeze. It's even more shocking to me that it froze in the *door* of my fridge, since that is the warmest place.

Is this normal for soy milk? If not, what went wrong? How should I store soy milk?

<sub>*The expiration date is sometime in March 2011</sub>

Comment: I have seen one weird fridge that actually had vents letting cool air in in the front from the freezer, through the same assembly as the ice dispenser... you don't have one of those, do you?

Comment: @Jefromi: Nope, I have never had anything in my door freeze.

Comment: Wow, then I'm as stumped as you are. I've seen it stored next to regular milk all the time, and I've never seen it freeze.

Comment: It's only the "warmest" due to opening/closing the door a lot, so the temperature cycles ... in the bottom of the door of a fridge where it hasn't been opened for a day or two can get colder than the top of the fridge.  But even with that, I find my eggs freeze before the soy milk will.

Comment: Is it actually frozen?  I've had soy milk (and coconut milk as well) just go completely solid in the fridge before.  Melting it over low heat reconstituted it again, but the texture wasn't quite 'right'

Comment: @Kimba: it's definitely frozen, I can hear and feel the ice crystals crunch when I squeeze the container.

Comment: same thing for me. ONLY the soymilk.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with Silk Unsweetened Organic Soy Milk. It's the only thing that froze (in fact, another brand of soy milk right next to it didn't freeze), and it wasn't in a colder part of the fridge or anything. It's kind of freaky. I didn't think something water-based could freeze at above 32 degrees.

Answer (score 4):

Have you ever put a quart-sized container of plain water in the spot where your soymilk froze? Perhaps that spot in your fridge is actually very cold--not cold enough to freeze milk with all its fat content (even skim as some), but enough to freeze soymilk (especially if it's settled and separated a bit).

Comment: Yes, if it will freeze soymilk, it will certainly freeze water. Freezing point depression and all.

Comment: I have a quart of water sitting in the same spot right now. I have not opened my refrigerator in the past 16 hours. I will check when I get home tonight.

Comment: It didn't freeze :-\ The soy milk is literally the only thing that has ever frozen in my refrigerator.

Comment: Well, it was worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same thing happen - in fact, I've had a brand new soy milk freeze solid, sitting next to the other carton of soy milk that is around half full, which isn't frozen. Both the same brand and type of soy milk - one frozen solid, one not frozen at all. So I suspect that something may go wrong in some batches of soy milk that affects the freezing temp, but I have no idea what. Mine is Silk brand, organic unsweetened.